# antlr4 - default context object

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to generate defaul context object?

Giving following simplified grammar

```
class {
    method* constructor? 
}
```

and parsed text:

```
SomeClass {
}
```

is it possible to make antlr interpret the input text as if there was a constructor?

```
SomeClass {
   SomeClass() {
   }
}
```

I could do some hacks in the class context listener to add constructor but It seems very messy. I wonder if there is any way to generate default "text" if the context object is not provided at the lowest level possible.

Answer (score -1):

Learn basicks Antlr.
There is a generated by ANTLR listener called (grammar name)BaseListener with method enter(rulename) or exit(rulename). 
I guess it is undestandable when the methods are called. 
You can overwrite the methods to do anything you want, calling a constructor for example if there will be a constructor rule. Then add this listener to the parcer.

Comment: If there is no constructor then no listener is going to be called. That is what the my point is. How to make antlr add default context objects (in places where they are not speicfied explicitly) BEFORE the parse tree is being build.

Comment: It is not normal usage.You can not, or you need to create the context instances manuelly. Thanks for -1